# How to set timer, even if App is closed?

Tags: java, android, timer

I habe a app for event informations an app which sends pushmessages. Now I want to give the user the option to disable the messages for a specific time (one hour, one day ...). I know how to dissable it compleatly, but how I can set it like I want (one hour...) even if the app is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the simple solution would be to `check if there is a time restriction is present` in the same place where you notify user for event information. If there is a time restriction dont show the notification else show it